# VBA Dictionary and multiple items aggregation

Tags: vba, dictionary

Im having issues with a dictionary. I have multiple invoices from the same customer and i want to sum them up. Therefore my Key is customer name and i want the Item to be sum of the invoices per customer.

I would also like to add a second Item which would be payments, that would also be summed up per customer.

Is there a way to do this? Ive been trying to sum the invoices below, but so far i'm only able to save the invoices to the dictionary. In the optimal situation, i would have customer name in column A, sum of invoices in column B and sum of payments in column C.

ps. Pivot is not an option.

Thank you for the assistance!

```
Sub Customers()

Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr2 As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long, n As Integer
Dim arr As Variant
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim Dict As New Dictionary

    'Define range

    With Blad6
        lr1 = Worksheets("ww").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = Worksheets("ww").Range("A2:A" & lr1 + 1)
    End With

    For x = 2 To UBound(arr)
    If Dict.Exists(Worksheets("ww").Cells(x, 2).Value) Then
        Dict(Cells(x, 1).Value) = Dict(Worksheets("ww").Cells(x, 2).Value) + Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 6).Value
        Else
        Dict.Add Worksheets("ww").Cells(x, 1).Value, Cells(x, 1).Offset(0, 6).Value

    End If

    Debug.Print Dict(Cells(x, 1).Value)

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doable through custom class type. First you create the class named clsINVOICE

```
Option Explicit

Private invvalue    As Double
Private invterm     As Integer

Public Property Let VALUE(ByVal dblvalue As Double)
    invvalue = dblvalue
End Property
Public Property Get VALUE() As Double
    VALUE = invvalue
End Property

Public Property Let TERM(ByVal intValue As Integer)
    invterm = intValue
End Property
Public Property Get TERM() As Integer
    TERM = invterm
End Property
```

Then you can use it to collect in your dictionary, like e.g.below

```
Sub UserTypeDictionary()

    Dim Dict        As New Dictionary
    Dim myinvoice   As New clsINVOICE

    myinvoice.VALUE = 12.34
    myinvoice.TERM = 14

    Dict.Add "myInvoiceNumber", myinvoice

    Debug.Print Dict("myInvoiceNumber").VALUE
    Debug.Print Dict("myInvoiceNumber").TERM

End Sub
```